# Problem in typesetting Devanagari text in Texlive 2016

Tags: xetex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,polyglossia,fontspec}
\setmainlanguage{sanskrit}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit 2003}
\begin{document}

अ आ इ ई उ ऊ ऋ ए ऐ ओ औ अं अः  

\end{document}
```

If I compile above sample using xelatex in Texlive 2016, I get the following font warning messages

> fontspec warning: "script-not-exist"
>
> Font 'Sanskrit 2003' does not contain script 'Devanagari'.

What is the reason for this and how should I fix it? In Texlive 2014 I didn't have this problem.

Comment: I can compile your code without any errors/warnings. Are you sure you have properly installed the font?

Comment: Yes I have installed the font in /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-indic-fonts-core/

Answer (score 4):

I get the warning too. The problem is that `Script=Devanagari` is mapped to two open type script tags. In fontspec-xetex.sty you can find:

```
 \newfontscript{Devanagari}{dev2,deva}
```

Sanskrit has the `deva` feature but not the `dev2` feature and when it checks (first) for `dev2` this triggers the warning. Imho the warning is confusing but harmless. You can avoid it by exchanging the order of the check by adding after fontspec:

```
 \newfontscript{Devanagari}{deva,dev2}
```

But then you probably will get it again if you use a font with `dev2` ;-(.

A better solution would be if fontspec would issue the warning only after it has processed the full list.

Comment: Why don't I get it then? Do I have a different version or something? I can't think of  a reason to explain this.

Comment: @Alenanno: I don't know. Perhaps your font is different and has dev2, or your fontspec is older (in tl14 I don't get the warning either).

Comment: After inserting \newfontscript{Devanagari}{deva,dev2} it is working. I mean no more warnings.

Thanks a lot

Comment: @UlrikeFischer — looks like I need to correct that :) https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/317

Comment: @UlrikeFischer — hmmm, did I fix this at some point? I can reproduce this now...

Comment: @WillRobertson It seems to be gone but while looking at it I found another perhaps related oddity and added a new issue to the tracker.